# Careers.SO should offer anti-searches

Tags: feature-request, jobs

You should be able to filter locations you do ***NOT*** want to work when searching on Careers.SO.

For example, I have no desire to relocate to NYC, CA, or some other places.

I should be able to remove those localities from my criteria when perusing job listings.

Comment: I suspect that advertising logic works against this.              
The site wants advertisers to see as many clicks as possible, they also want candidates to see lots of jobs posted.

Comment: @MartinBeckett - they may want candidates to see lots of job listings, but wading-through dozens, scores, or hundreds from locales I won't consider is a waste of time

Comment: Until they have no visitors because people are fed up of doing that - then the current strategy wins.

Comment: To clarify, location-specific searches are not sufficient for you (e.g. php jobs in Toledo, php jobs in Austin, etc)? Am I correct in inferring you are interested in relocating anywhere in the world except a few specific locations?

Comment: @Mike - that is what I said in the OP: being able to anti-filter locales should be possible. I can setup places will to relocate to in my profile - why shouldn't I be able to filter search for places I don't want to be?

Comment: I was trying to get an understanding of your needs, rather than think only about your proposed solution. My intuitive impression is that your need (willing to relocate anywhere... except X, Y, and Z) is very rare. Regarding profile relocation, we only permit the specification of a single city. This hits the needs of the vast majority, which also informs and is reinforced by our search design (filter results to a single city).

Comment: @Mike - you may want to check the allowed cities list for relocation: I have 7 states and one city listed in my profile. Almost everyone I know who is open to relocation is open to a wide range of locales, with only certain exceptions. Maybe my circles are different from yours, but that encompasses hundreds of folks I've worked with, gone to school with, etc.

Comment: @warren, fair enough, assuming "wide range of locales" means all locales except for a subset. Even then, I'm inclined to think people have strong preferences (e.g. the list on your profile). Anyway, no plans for this as of yet, but we'll keep this scenario is mind. (Btw, I stand corrected about multiple locations on profile. Still, this is conceptually different from "all locations minus a few".)

Comment: +1 This is how search engines/criteria should work, and for good reason; eg, if 99% of results are x,y and you don't want x,y, you shouldn't have to specify {a,b,..,w,z}. Especially if the set is unbounded; eg I'd like to exclude php, objective-c & iOS; but the number of technologies I would consider (and can do) is not only a long list, but explicitly listing them might unintentionally filter out wanted results (eg, maybe a "scala" job is just tagged "akka", or a hadoop job just tagged "hive").

Comment: @michael_n - hadn't thought about listing tech you didn't want to work with: but that is an excellent parallel